# Is there a SQL INSERT Statement to Insert Records from Previous Month if Not exists for Current Month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

TableA:

```
ID   Amount  Date
-------------------------
1     100    02/02/2020
2     100    02/02/2020

1     100    03/10/2020  Insert Feb record with March date
2     100    03/10/2020  Insert Feb record with March date
3     100    03/10/2020
4     100    03/10/2020

1     100    04/03/2020  
4     100    04/03/2020
2     100    04/03/2020  Insert MAR record with APR date
3     100    04/03/2020  Insert MAR record with APR date
```

The `Processing Date` is always different.

I tried using `NOT EXISTS` but it selects all old rows, but I only need previous date rows only

```
DECLARE @ProcessingDate DateTime
SET @ProcessingDate = '04/03/2020'

SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.ID, Amount, ProcessingDate
FROM 
    TABLE1 t1
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELET *
                FROM TABLE1 t2
                WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID  
                  AND t2.ProcessingDate = @ExpenseProcessingDate)
```

I tried using the `LAG` function but it's also selecting all records

```
DECLARE @ProcessingDate DateTime
SET @ProcessingDate = '04/03/2020'

SELECT
    *,
    LAG(@ProcessingDate) OVER (Partition BY ID, Amount ORDER BY ProcessingDate) AS PrevEvent
FROM 
    Table1 A
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 A1
                WHERE A1.ID = A.ID 
                  AND A1.ProcessingDate = @ProcessingDate)
```

Comment: FYI: Consistent casing (and layout) of T-SQL makes it much easier to read.

Comment: Without knowing your goal and a description of the logic you need to implement, Nor does it help to (presumably) combine your source data with your expected results - even with comments. In addition, obscure comments like "Processing Date is always different" are only meaningful to you. You need to clarify what you are trying to accomplish. Lastly DISTINCT is often a kludge to cover up other problems. Explain why you attempted to use it.

Comment: Thank You SMor I want to insert ONLY Previous month record if there was no records ran for latest processing date. The queries I tried selecting all previous month's but I am looking only for last month

Comment: `FROM Table2 t1 .... FROM Table1 t2.....` - ***seriously?!?*** This blatantly violates the *Principle of Least Surprise" - if you have a `Table1` - everyone would expect the alias `t1` to reference **that** table - not `Table2` (and vice-versa) ......You're just- totally unnecessarily - making life hard on yourself (and anyone who must read your code) with something like this......

Comment: @marc_s if you have a Table1 - everyone would expect the alias t1 to reference that table -This is true and I would like to reference same table but for better understanding of question I used example of two table. Can you please help if I only have Table2  and I want to Insert Previous month record for latest Processing date if No record came in?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you are asking... but to further filter your query down to only the previous month, use the following:

```
declare @ProcessingDate datetime = '04/03/2020', @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime;

select @StartDate = getdate();
select @StartDate = convert(datetime, '01/' + convert(varchar(2), datepart(month, dateadd(month, -1, @StartDate))) + '/' + datename(year, dateadd(month, -1, @StartDate)), 103);
select @EndDate = dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, @StartDate));

-- select @StartDate StartDate, @EndDate EndDate

SELECT t1.ID,Amount, ProcessingDate
FROM dbo.Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID  
    AND t1.ProcessingDate = @ExpenseProcessingDate
)
-- Only include records from the previous month
AND t2.ProcessingDate >= @StartDate AND t2.ProcessingDate < dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate);
```

Note I changed the aliases to match the table names for clarity.

I keep a bunch of standard code snippets lying around for reports e.g. last month, last quarter, last week etc.